# error xxx in yyy does not name a type

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, g++, c++14

Compiling file `error_xxx_does_not_name_a_type.cpp`, why do I get error
`error_xxx_does_not_name_a_type.cpp:5:28: error: ‘A’ in ‘struct std::pair<bool, int>’ does not name a type std::pair<bool, int> ::A::B::C::D::get_i()`

```
// error_xxx_does_not_name_a_type.h
#pragma once
#include <utility>

namespace A{ namespace B{ namespace C{
struct D
{   
    std::pair<bool, int> get_i();
    std::pair<bool, int> get_j();
    std::pair<bool, int> get_k();
    int get_l();
};  
}}}
```

and

```
// error_xxx_does_not_name_a_type.cpp
#include "error_xxx_does_not_name_a_type.h"

#if 1 // gives me the error
std::pair<bool, int> ::A::B::C::D::get_i()
{ return {true, 10}; }
#endif
// But none of the below do
// missing ::
std::pair<bool, int> A::B::C::D::get_j()
{ return {true, 10}; }
// trailing return type
auto ::A::B::C::D::get_k()->
    std::pair<bool, int>
{ return {true, 10}; }
// return type int
int ::A::B::C::D::get_l()
{ return 10; }
```

I have compiled with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -c error_xxx_does_not_name_a_type.cpp` and on `g++ (Ubuntu 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) 5.3.0 20151204`

Comment: Surprised there's not a high-voted dupe of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because  (space) is irrelevant in this context and `::` is used as scope resolution operator, applied to `std::pair<bool, int>`.

For the compiler,

```
std::pair<bool, int>::A...
```

is the same as

```
std::pair<bool, int>:: A...
```

and the same as

```
std::pair<bool, int> ::A...
```

and the same as

```
std::pair<bool, int> :: A...
```

Thus, the compiler is looking for an `A` within the scope of `std::pair<bool, int>` which does obviously fail.

See: [Space(s) before/after the scope resolution operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452027/spaces-before-after-the-scope-resolution-operator)

Comment: Explanation but no solution

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah, so what? The question was: "why do I get error ...". Workarounds are provided in the question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c9b2ec165c8cc1d)'s a terser reproducing example:

```
struct T{};
T A();
T ::A() { return T(); }

// error: no 'int T::A()' member function declared in class 'T'
```

(Note the auto-`int` return type attempted by GCC as a holdover from C!)

This is a C++ quirk. You're confusing the parser, because it looks like you're trying to do something with `std::pair<bool, int> ::A::B::C::D`, which obviously doesn't exist. (The spacing is ignored here, despite the way we conventionally write.)

Just leave out the `::`. With a function definition, you never need it anyway.